# Query hangs on "Creating Sort Index"

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

Used to have a query that ran for a minute and now takes close to an hour after changing to a new table with a slightly different schema.

Query:

```
select 
    date(datetime_field)
    ,str_1
    ,str_2
    ,str_3
    ,str_4
    ,dayname(datetime_field)
    ,str_5
    ,date(convert_tz(datetime_field, 'Timezone', t.timezone))
    ,time(convert_tz(cpt_datetime, 'Timezone', t.timezone))
    ,sum_field_1
    ,sum_field_2 
from 
(select 
    concat_ws(' ', date_date, date_time) as datetime_field
    ,str_1
    ,str_2
    ,str_3
    ,str_4
    ,ceiling(sum(agg_field1)) as sum_field_1
    ,ceiling(sum(agg_field2)) as sum_field_2 
from raw_table f 
force index(raw_table_index) 
join lookup_table c on f.str_3 = c.str_3 and f.id_2 = c.id_2 
where str_3 = 'VALUE' 
and id_1 = 0 
and f.id_2 in ('val1','val2') 
and date_date >= '2018-04-12' 
group by concat_ws(' ', date_date, date_time)
,str_1
,str_2
,str_3
,str_4
,c.str_5) 
fcst left join timezones_table t on fcst.str_2 = t.str_2;
```

And the table has the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE `raw_table` ADD INDEX raw_table_index (id_2, id_1, str_3, date_date);
```

The explain shows that it is using the index on the table:

```
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: f
         type: ref
possible_keys: raw_table_index
          key: raw_table_index
      key_len: 171
          ref: const,const,func
         rows: 414
        Extra: Using index condition
```

and

```
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 38088
        Extra: NULL
```

So it's filtering down to 38,088 on a table that has 40M+

The query is in the "sending data" state for about 128 seconds and then spends close to 2 hours in the "creating sort index" state. I've played around with different indexes and not seen any improvement. The current index is very similar to the index on the old table. Not sure if I'm doing something really dumb and just missing something? Any thoughts?

Comment: 38k for "rows" is just a guess by MySQL; run the inner `select` up to `and date_date >= '2018-04-12'` seperately (also once without this date filter) to get actual numbers. Depending on these counts, you may want to either use an index to support the filter or the grouping. Also, check your index on the lookup table (or, preferable, add the complete explain output), it might be the actual problem here. Also, is `and f.id_2 in ('val1','val1')` a typo (twice the same value)? If they are (or can be) different, having them as first column in the index can be less optimal.

Comment: @Solarflare what exactly do you mean by use a filter to support grouping? The filter on date_date is not in the index only because it is only used to filter out 1 or 2 days out of 56, so adding it to the index wouldn't do much. Also, that was a typo, so I'll update the index and see if that helps. I'm not sure the index is the problem tho, in that it spends all of its time in the "creating sort index" phase, which is after it has scanned the data, from what I understand

Comment: I meant: either you use an index to help the `where` (like you have), this is useful if your inner select (before grouping, but including the join) has a small resultset (e.g. your 38k), or you add a new one with the `group by` columns to prevent the need to sort (if you get e.g. several million rows for the inner query); which is why I asked for the number of rows. But again, also check if you have an index for the lookup table `(id_2, str_3)` (or add the full explain output, it might give some additional insight; it's a bit hard to guess). Also check if you have enough hdd/temp space.

Comment: You have a `JOIN`, but no clue of which table each column is in (in the `WHERE`); this missing information is vital to helping with performance.

Comment: Having a date and a time in two separate fields is usually folly; I suspect this query suffers from that.